# Rolling month script

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to provide a rolling 12 month view of our 'dormant' clients by region each month (dormant = haven't placed an order in past 12 months). Below is stripped down piece of the script (minus the necessary joins).

```
select region, count(clientID)as TotalDormant
FROM clients
WHERE test_account = 'NO'
AND DATEDIFF(curdate(), last_order_date) > 365
GROUP BY 1
```

Returning...

```
Region  Total Dormant  
ROW     500  
US      1000
```

However...because of the `curdate()` it's only returning the dormant customers who have been inactive for a full year leading up to today (9/17/2015). I need it to return the number of dormant clients we had on each of the past 11 months.

Any help on what I'll need to do to return the number dormant for each month on a rolling 12m basis by region?

I have tried `inner join`, subqueries etc...but they all wind up messing up even septembers data (which is accurate using the basic query above). So I decided to strip it down, ask for advice, and build from there.

Comment: Do you want to return all clients that are inactive more than year grouping by months? Right or not? Because it's a little bit unclear for me

Comment: Yes, sorry. Grouping by Region and Month.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **DATE_FORMAT** function to get your month in the date:

```
select region, count(clientID) as TotalDormant,
  DATE_FORMAT(last_order_date,'%Y %m') AS dormantSince
FROM clients
WHERE test_account = 'NO'
AND DATEDIFF(curdate(), last_order_date) > 365
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(last_order_date,'%Y %m');
```

When also placed in the **GROUP BY**, the query will give your the dormance since a certain month.